# Printing strings next to each output row in sql?

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, oracle

I have been looking for an answer to this question. I have a table called "Tree" that contains pid of the node and another column that contains parent pid (ppid). And the table contains:

```
Pid     Ppid
1           2
3           2
5           6
7           6
2           4
6           4
4           15
8           9
10      9
12      13
14      13
9           11
13      11
11      15
15      NULL
```

The aim is to print a message next to the Pid column stating the type of node, ie "Leaf", "Inner" or "Root", in a single query using Oracle/sql/sql server/etc. 
The output is supposed to be something like this:

```
1           Leaf
2           Inner
3           Leaf
4           Inner
5           Leaf
6           Inner
7           Leaf
8           Leaf
9           Inner
10      Leaf
11      Inner
12      Leaf
13      Inner
14      Leaf
15      Root
```

I just need to know the way of printing the new column values. Can someone please help me? 
Thank you in advance :)

Comment: so, mysql, SQL Server or Oracle?, pick one

Comment: **in a single query using Oracle/sql/sql server/etc** really

Comment: And then show us where you've got to and which specific part you're stuck on...

Comment: Any, sql or mysql or Oracle or sql server

Comment: I don't even know a way to start, please help

Comment: They all have different syntax for this sort of thing. Oracle has hierarchical queries and 11gR2 onwards also has recursive CTEs, which I think SQL Server supports, but don't think MySQL does (not sure, only use Oracle). Do you really need something that works in any RDBMS, or do you just not know which one you are using?

Comment: do you need a solution that works, with no modifications, on every DBMS? or do you need a solution that works on one of them, random? and what have you tried / searched so far?

Comment: A solution that works on any one of them, sql or mysql or Oracle or sql server, any using any technique

Comment: I know how to get the first column and that is all

Comment: Let me say, you're not showing so much effort... You know how to do select *,  nothing more, and you made no effort at all, no search, no attempts...

Comment: I am new to this and this question has been imposed on me by my professors and I have no idea of how to print a non existing value. This concept isn't present in any of the textbooks that I know of and since I don't know what it is called, I am unable to get the right keywords for a Google search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In  `SQL SERVER` & `Oracle` it can achieved using `Recursive CTE`

This is for `SQL SERVER`

```
;WITH data
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   (VALUES (1,2 ),
                        (3,2 ),
                        (5,6 ),
                        (7,6 ),
                        (2,4 ),
                        (6,4 ),
                        (4,15 ),
                        (8,9 ),
                        (10,9 ),
                        (12,13 ),
                        (14,13 ),
                        (9,11 ),
                        (13,11 ),
                        (11,15 ),
                        (15,NULL ) ) tc (Pid, Ppid)),
     rec_cte
     AS (SELECT *
         FROM   data
         UNION ALL
         SELECT d.*
         FROM   rec_cte rc
                JOIN data d
                  ON rc.Ppid = d.Pid)
--select * from rec_cte
    SELECT Pid,
           CASE Count(Ppid)
             WHEN 0 THEN 'root'
             WHEN 1 THEN 'leaf'
             ELSE 'inner'
           END level
    FROM   rec_cte
    GROUP  BY Pid
```

**Result :**

```
╔═════╦═══════╗
║ Pid ║ level ║
╠═════╬═══════╣
║   1 ║ leaf  ║
║   2 ║ inner ║
║   3 ║ leaf  ║
║   4 ║ inner ║
║   5 ║ leaf  ║
║   6 ║ inner ║
║   7 ║ leaf  ║
║   8 ║ leaf  ║
║   9 ║ inner ║
║  10 ║ leaf  ║
║  11 ║ inner ║
║  12 ║ leaf  ║
║  13 ║ inner ║
║  14 ║ leaf  ║
║  15 ║ root  ║
╚═════╩═══════╝
```

Comment: Here "data" refers to the table "Tree"?

Comment: @PrakharSaxena - yes.. for demo I have used table valued constructor. Replace it with your table name

Comment: How do I skip the column name row?

Comment: @PrakharSaxena Where is Column name row ?

Comment: @PrakharSaxena - In which DBMS you are executing ?

Comment: It works perfectly, thanks a lot for the solution

Comment: I ran in Oracle, it threw an error, then I typed it in Sql server, works perfectly now, thanks a lot :)